# Reflection vs indices of refraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

A magician during a show makes a glass lens with refractive index 1.47 disappear in a trough of liquid. What is the refractive index of the liquid?
Could anyone please demonstrate with a ray diagram?

Comment: The refractive index of the liquid is 1.47. Search for Fresnel reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fresnel reflection coefficients (i.e. the fraction of light that is reflected at an interface) are for s-polarised,
$$
R_\mathrm{s} = 
\left|\frac{n_1\cos\theta_{\mathrm{i}}-n_2\cos\theta_{\mathrm{t}}}{n_1\cos\theta_{\mathrm{i}}+n_2\cos\theta_{\mathrm{t}}}\right|^2
$$
and p-polarised light,
$$
R_\mathrm{p} =
\left|\frac{n_1\cos\theta_{\mathrm{t}}-n_2\cos\theta_{\mathrm{i}}}{n_1\cos\theta_{\mathrm{t}}+n_2\cos\theta_{\mathrm{i}}}\right|^2
$$

The lens can dispear when submered in the liquid when the total reflectivity is equal to zero,

$$
R = \frac{R_s +  R_p}{2} = 0
$$

This happens only when $n_1=n_2$, so we know that the liquid must have a refractive index of 1.47.

**NB** I made use of Snell's law,

$$
\frac{\sin\theta_\mathrm{i}}{\sin\theta_\mathrm{t}} = \frac{n_2}{n_1}
$$

when $n_1 = n_2$, it follows that $\theta_\mathrm{i} = \theta_\mathrm{t}$.

Go on, hand in your homework and get fully marks, but make sure you understand why.